# Masonry and BootStrap 3 dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, masonry

I'm trying to use masonry within a BootStrap 3 dropdown menu.

What I'm finding is that the following declarations:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}

.open > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Are causing a conflict with Masonry in that it is unable to determine the Menus width and height to organise the elements within.

I find if I change the above declarations to:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.open > .dropdown-menu {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

voila - Happy days. Issue is I'm unable to change Bootstrap.css due to it being served from the CDN in prod.

I have tried to re-declare in my custom.css, however as I'm using visibility rather then display.. Display rule are not being overwritten.

Has any one had similar experiences, or have any suggestions how I may be able to remove the declarations from Bootstrap.css and use the ones in my custom.css?

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite bootstraps declarations if you load your custom css file after bootstrap. Then you can use the css selectors you need and overwrite bootstraps values with your own.

Comment: thanks though the issue is you need to overwrite the same properties in the custom as Bootstrap.. Otherwise they just combine...

Its like I need to remove the Bootstrap reference from the DOM altogether or clear the property some how. So then the visibility rules can kick off.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer in this case was to re-declare the .dropdown class.

Looks to be working well now.